# How do I generate ESP trafic (IPv6)?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, ipsec, wireshark

I have this topology:

[image]

I only have moon and sun. After the connection was successfully established, I need to generate ESP packets for wireshark capture.

How do I generate ESP packets?

When I use IPv4 addresses, it works by sending ping from one host to another, but when I use IPv6, I don't see the same results.

Comment: Can you ping IPv6 address on other server?

Comment: Yes, I can do that

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packet which is sent from and to protected subnets will be encapsulated by strongswan. If traffic is not matching criteria won't be encapsulated.
Try to generate ping from interface which is included within protected subnet. 
For example from moon gateway: 
ping6 -I eth1 fec2::1
That should match criteria for your design and packet should be encapsulated.

Comment: OK. But why ping6 generates ESP trafic?